# Excel own dialog box on Workbook_BeforeClose event, option for Cancel

Tags: excel, vba

My code looks like this now, the only problem left to solve is how to get Cancel without displaying built-in dialog box. If I click Yes or No, everything works fine. However when I click Cancel built-in dialog box pops up and I have to click Cancel again. How to make Cancel work like Cancel, so there wouldn't be built-in dialog box popping up?

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    If Not closing Then
        answer = MsgBox("Save data?", vbYesNoCancel + vbQuestion, "Save data?")

        If answer = vbYes Or answer = vbNo Then
            closing = True
            On Error Resume Next

        Application.Visible = False

        Application.DisplayFormulaBar = True
        ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = True
        ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = True

        ThisWorkbook.Unprotect Password:="123456"

        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Start").Visible = True

        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Start").Activate

        ThisWorkbook.Protect Password:="123456", Structure:=True, Windows:=False
            ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=answer = vbYes
        Else
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Here is how it looks like (I use Office 2016):

[image]

Comment: No repro in Excel 2013, MsgBox is the only dialog if Cancel is chosen.

Comment: `However when I click Cancel built-in dialog box pops up and I have to click Cancel again.` I am not experiencing the same behaviour. When I press cnacel, nothing happens as expected

Comment: Do you get the same results if you copy only the shown code to an empty workbook? If yes - add Excel version. If no - there is something else involved in the file and you have to check what it is and include in question.

Comment: If I create a new workbook and insert this code there then Cancel work as No. Workbook just closes without saving.

Comment: This looks really weird, so either there is something wrong with 2016 or your installation (maybe some addons?). The only advice left to offer is to put breakpoint in the first line of the code and then see what happens when you press Cancel (run it step by step with F8 and inspect variable values).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem: `ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=answer = vbYes`

It fires the BeforeClose event again. So you should disable the events beforehand and re-enable them afterwards.

```
Application.EnableEvents=False
ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=answer = vbYes
Application.EnableEvents=True
```

Comment: This line is not reached when the answer is Cancel.

Comment: When I tested the code, the MsgBox only opened twice when clicking Yes or No. Canceling worked as expected. The code I wrote fixes that problem. Maybe @user7202022 made changes to the code before posting it here, so I get the opposite problem from him. And even if that's not it, he could disable the events at the start of the Sub and re-enable them at the very end.

Comment: I suspect that the `closing` variable is global and designed as reentrancy guard, but still the question is about Cancel behavior.